# How to get the sum of numbers via map?

Tags: javascript

How to get the sum of elements (numbers) that I get from the database?

```js
const onSum = () => {
  return invoiceList.map(i => {
    // i.number summ
  })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `Array.prototype.reduce()` instead.

> The **reduce()** method executes a **reducer** function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

```js
const invoiceList = [20, 10, 5, 10]

function arrSum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0)
}

console.log(arrSum(invoiceList)) // 45
```

What if your invoice list is an object instead of an array? You can use `Object.values` (which returns an array of values) before calling the same function as above.

```js
var invoiceObject = {'a': 20,'b': 10,'c': 5,'d': 10}

function arrSum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0)
}

console.log( arrSum(Object.values(invoiceObject)) )
```

---

Further reading:
- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simpler to read or understand:

```
const onSum = () => {
  let sum = 0
  invoiceList.forEach(i => {
    sum += i
  })
  return sum
};
```

forEach does something for each item in an array. Map builds a new array.